# How to use conditional types on NaN and Infinity

Tags: typescript, types, nan, infinity, conditional-types

I am creating a function in TypeScript that essentially extends the functionality of the `typeof` keyword, including showing the appropriate IntelliSense for the type whenever it is known (via conditional types). I have it working just fine for all my other custom types so they only show IntelliSense for 1 return type when it is known, but I am not sure how to make it work specifically for the NaN and Infinity values. I believe this is because these are being overlooked as "number" literal types. (working example below)

```js
public static async type(value: number): Promise<'number' | 'nan' | 'infinity'> // would rather this only show just 1 type
public static async type(value: []): Promise<'array'>
public static async type(value: Promise<any>): Promise<'promise'>
// and several more...
public static async type(value: any): Promise<T_detectType> {
   // do stuff
}
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to create a conditional type based on NaN and/or Infinity? (non-working example below)

```js
public static async type(value: NaN): Promise<'nan'>
public static async type(value: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY | Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY): Promise<'infinity'>
```

---

I am able to give more details as necessary, but I am unsure what you may need and I am trying to keep this question concise.

Comment: TypeScript does not have numeric literal types corresponding to `NaN` or `Infinity` or `-Infinity`.  It was suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15135](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135) and declined; it gets brought up occasionally as a suggestion but has never been implemented.  So there's no support for what you're trying to do

Comment: Also see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36964

Comment: @jcalz Thanks you! Can you add this as an answer? I would like to allow some extra time to see if someone can come up with a workable alternative. However, I would assume you are completely in the right and will mark it as the correct answer tomorrow if no one provides a workable alternative.

Comment: @NicholasSummers no one will provide workable alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better or worse, TypeScript does not have [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) representing `NaN`, `Infinity`, or `-Infinity`.  The narrowest type available for `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` is just `number`. So, for example, while a `const` initialized with a numeric literal will generally have a literal type:

```
const x = 1.234;
// const x: 1.234
```

The same does not happen with `NaN` or `Infinity`:

```
const y = NaN;
// const y: number
const z = -Infinity;
// const z: number
```

---

There's no workaround I can think of for this that isn't significantly worse than just giving up.  You could imagine providing some [simulated nominal type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)

```
type NaN = number & { NaN: true };
type Infinity = number & { Infinity: true };
type NegInfinity = number & { NegInfinity: true };
```

But then you'd need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to use them:

```
const w = NaN as NaN;
const v = Infinity as Infinity;
const u = -Infinity as NegInfinity;
```

and if your goal is to write `Blah.type(NaN)` and have `Promise<'nan'>` come out, you could only achieve that goal by writing `Blah.type(NaN as NaN)` which is silly, especially because nothing stops someone from writing `Blah.type(123 as NaN)`.

In TypeScript, `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` are just of type `number`, and that's that.

---

As for changing this:

There is a declined feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#15135](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135) asking for such support.  From reading that issue (and the linked design discussion at [ms/TS#15356](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15356)) it looks like nobody was able to articulate an important enough use case to support it.  Supporting `NaN` as a literal might be annoying because, for example, `NaN === NaN` is `false`.

Personally, I'm inclined to agree that we care about `NaN` types because they are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and tracking falsiness is something worthwhile.  But in the pull request implementing numeric literal types, a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407#issuecomment-230594724) by the implementer says that falsiness doesn't matter, and he can't think of any meaningful "scenarios where you'd use `NaN` and `Infinity` as singleton types, discriminant values, or literal values for overloading."

There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#32277](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32277) asking for `Infinity` and `-Infinity` literal types as opposed to `NaN`; it's currently labeled as "awaiting more feedback" which means they want to see comments describing compelling use cases before considering implementing it.

And there's an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#36964](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36964) that demonstrates how the lack of consideration of a `NaN`-like type causes incorrect narrowings... a falsy `number` is assumed to be `0` whereas it should really be `0 | typeof NaN` to be correct.  It's also labeled as awaiting feedback, and the requester seems to be saying that it should be `number` since `typeof NaN` is `number` (as opposed to saying that there should be a `NaN` type).  But it's relevant.

It's just about conceivable that enough people could add comments to those two open issues saying how literal `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` types should be added, and detailing use cases that are persuasive enough to eventually cause this to happen.  But it's quite likely that this will not happen.  And it seems to me very unlikely that stronger typing of a `typeof` helper function is going to be seen as particularly compelling.  So while it might not hurt anything to go there and give them a  and describe what you're trying to do, I wouldn't count on it having any effect.

For now, I think you should probably just give up on trying to distinguish `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` from `number`, unfortunately.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-bHTG8fzumAWKnfYny7D9odDvwFSBw6ItFoEcECJ3mhQYK0AGpyCA6cDsbZcHZoZ6tL7GAS9gdDkdgP5ZsUAIihYHXsKAA)